# How can I see digital signature in assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-assembly

I read article about "Signing an Assembly with a Strong Name";
http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/dot-net-assemblies-and-strong-name-signature/;
then I learned to get public key and public key token;
but the question :;
How can I get the digital signature from the assembly?
and how I can extract the hash from the digital signature?
I prefer to use ildasm;
 thank you;

Comment: What exactly do you want to see? Do you want to check it for yourself or do you have to write code to check it?

Comment: The article already mentions using the `sn` tool to verify the signature , display the token with `sn -T`(probably what you mean by hash) or extract the public key. Have you tried it?

Comment: I want to see the hash.

Comment: to  Panagiotis Kanavos, No, the hash isn't the publickeytoken;

Answer (score 2):

One way is to do this from C#, if you would prefer it:

```
// Load the certificate from your DLL file

var cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile("path to your assembly");

// Create an instance of X509Certificate2

var cert2 = new X509Certificate2(cert);

// Use `GetCertHash()` to extract certificate's hash

var hash = cert2.GetCertHash();
```

Documentation about types used:

X509Certificate: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

X509Certificate2:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx